# Cat after command in zmap

Tags: linux, shell, cat

I'm using zmap to scan.

```
zmap –-bandwith=10M –-target-port=80 –-output-file=results.csv 2.64.0.0/13 2.248.0.0/13
```

This works. But I have a file, ip.txt, containing hundreds of addresses. I want to scan all them. Do you know how to get it as "input"?

I'm thinking about:

```
zmap –-bandwith=10M –-target-port=80 –-output-file=results.csv cat ip.txt
```

...but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-w` (whitelist) option.

```
zmap -w ip.txt ...
```

(I'm not sure if you can use plain IP addresses, or if you need to convert them to CIDR prefixes first, i.e., change 192.0.2.42 to 192.0.2.42/32.)

---

Along the lines of what you were trying, you could try

```
zmap –-bandwith=10M –-target-port=80 –-output-file=results.csv $(cat ip.txt)
```

although this is somewhat fragile and will fail if `ip.txt` is too long; your operating system will limit the size of the arguments that can be passed to a command.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `;` to separate multiple commands in one line:

```
zmap –-bandwith=10M –-target-port=80 –-output-file=results.csv; cat ip.txt
```

If you want to execute the `cat` command only if the `zmap` command succeeded, then you can use the boolean `and` operator `&&`:

```
zmap –-bandwith=10M –-target-port=80 –-output-file=results.csv && cat ip.txt
```

Comment: And it may be even better to use `&&` to make sure the `cat` command is executed just if the first one was successful.

Comment: @fedorqui It depends on what is desired. However, added that to the answer. Thx!

Comment: I thought the question was how to use `ip.txt` as the list of addresses to scan.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use ip.txt as the list of addresses. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @KristofferÖrstadius Can you show how `ip.txt` looks like?

Comment: are all addresses in one line?

Comment: No, one per line, but I couldn't do enter in this form. :)

Comment: Ok. Just a hint: The comment form isn't meant to post file contents. Click "edit" below the question and put it there. Also note that a question needs to contain everything which is necessary to reproduce the problem, contents (or at least a part) of input files are necessary.